# Use Taylor Polynomial to approximate a definite integral.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

i have this problem:

**Get the Taylor Polynomial of grade 3 of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ at the point a=0
Then use the polynomial to approximate the definite integral:**

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{10} \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

Here is what I did:

Taylor polynomial degree 3, center a=0:

$1+x+x^2+x^3$

then I replace $x$ for $x^2$ and I have:

$1+x^2+x^4+x^6$

then integrating

$(0.1)+\frac{(0.1)^3}{3}+\frac{(0.1)^5}{5}+\frac{(0.1)^7}{7}$

and that is the result.

Is this correct? I mostly taught myself through books and have no way of checking if i understood the topic correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Looks correct (except I will nag you for not putting $\mathrm dx$ at the end of your integral)

Comment: This is OK. This is a frequent approach in the approximate integration.

Comment: What allows you to replace $x$ by $x^2$.

Comment: It's just an algebraic substitution? @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It's because $x^2$ goes to zero as well as $x$. we cannot replace $x$ by $x^2+1$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah sure we can, it's just an algebraic substitution. Whether or not the result is a good approximation or not is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for any integer $n\ge0$, we define the polynomial
$$p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k$$
which is the $n$-th order Taylor polynomial for $\frac1{1-x}$. So the polynomial for $\frac1{1-x^2}$ is of course
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{2k}$$
and thus
$$Q_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_0^{1/10}x^{2k}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{10^{2k+1}(2k+1)}$$
which confirms your results.